# Java Functions Passing & Returning Complex Data Types

Tags: java, parameter-passing

I'm in the process of learning Java and can't help but wonder how exactly Java passes function parameters and return values. I've done some search and found that Java only passes Objects by value. However, some people challenge this; they claim that when handling Complex Data Types (not Primitive like e.g. `int`) it only passes a pointer.

Does this mean that whatever changes are made to the local object affect the original one? Is there any way to pass "PURELY" by value (i.e. make a hard copy of an Object)?

Furthermore, what is true about the return value? For example, we use accessors (or getter functions - I'm not completely sure how they are called) to protect the private Attributes of an ADT from being changed to "illegal" values. If Java passes the Pointer, then whatever changes I make to the returned Object of an Accessor Function also affect the actual Attribute, if it isn't a Primitive Data Type, don't they?

Could anybody please help me clarify these concepts?
Thank you in Advance! :D

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference?rq=1 - and return values are the same, basically. The return value is either a primitive value, or a reference. Never an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to understand that Java passes **everything by value**. And this is also true for objects: *It passes **the pointers by values**.* So, it does not create a copy of the object, but of the reference.

The same goes for returning. So, yes, your thinking is right: you can modify the attributes (called class members) objects because they get returned in the form of a pointer. That is the reason why (if needed) someone could choose to design a class whose objects are is not modifiable once it is created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Imagine that you have an Attribute of type String. Then, will actually an accessor return a Pointer to that String? If yes, what prevents a user from changing it to an arbitrary value? (suppose that this String must take one among some allowed values)

Comment: String in Java are designed to be immutable in order to prevent that. If you want to "modify" a String, you will have to make a copy of it.

Comment: OK, that was probably a wrong example... I'm sorry for my mistakes, I'm not experienced in Java yet. What would happen if I had some Attribute of another Type instead? Wouldn't it be completely exposed to the user?

Comment: Yes, if no other measures are taken, the user can modify the object if he wants.

Comment: OK, I understand... Could I also ask what kind of other measures can be taken here or should I better ask another question? :)

Comment: The object returned to the called could be an instance of a class which only has getters and no setters. Or the object could be an instance of a class that is extending the baseclass and overrides all methods that makes changes to the object and make them throw an exception (eg: `Collections.unmodifiableList` does such a thing). The class also could have a built-in flag that indicates wether the object is allowed to be modified or not and checks against that flag in every method that changes some properties.

Comment: Or sometimes the function can just create a new object that's a copy of an existing one.  That would be the approach I'd take if the function returns something like a [`Dimension`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html) that basically just encapsulates a couple numbers.  If you have a function that returns the dimensions of some graphical object, you wouldn't want to return a `Dimension` that's stored in the object because then the client could modify it, but you can easily return a new `Dimension` with the same values.

Comment: @ajb: Nice addition. That is indeed a commonly used approach.

Comment: So that whatever the changes, they are only applied to the copy! I still have much to learn here... ;)

Answer (score 0):

> I've done some search and found that Java only passes Objects by
>   value.

There is your confusion. You cannot "pass objects" in Java, because objects are not values in Java. The only types in Java are primitive types and reference types (references are pointers to objects). So the only values you can manipulate in Java are primitives and pointers to objects. All types are passed or assigned by value.

Comment: Yes, I know. It passes a Pointer to the location where the Object is located in Memory. However, there is no Pointer type in Java, that's why I had some trouble expressing myself...

Comment: @angel: Well no, every type that is not a primitive type is a pointer type. References are pointers to objects. Reference types are pointer types.